# Simple scheduler library db for SQL Server in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I would like to schedule to run simple SPs to run in my Azure DB. Options: run once and simple recurring by days, weeks, months. As SQL Server Agent is not available in Azure, I am wondering is there any simple scheduling library, db which has this functionality. I would not like reinvent the wheel.

Please do not recommend to run the SQL Server Agent outside and connect to the Azure DB thats not and option.

In case of there is no such T-SQL library (I have to implement it from scratch) could anyone point me how can I implement simple recurring run SP, which runs in every say 5 seconds in *Azure*.

Thx in advance

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine to execute from WorkerRole use [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler). Ideally this kind of background job should be executed from worker role only.

However this library can be scheduled from **web application** also.But I don't prefer this as we may have multiple web roles, take double care while using in web application.

I am using FluentScheduler for my application on Azure (WorkerRole), It works great. It is also very easy to implement.

**Example**

```
 Schedule<DailyDigest>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(5).Seconds();
 Schedule<DailyDigest>().ToRunOnceAt(18, 0).AndEvery(24).Hours();
 Schedule<WeeklyDigest>().ToRunOnceAt(DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday).AddHours(18)).AndEvery(1).Weeks();
```

In above example, **DailyDigest** and **WeeklyDigest** are the classes inheriting from ITASK

```
public class DailyDigest : ITask
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        //Get Daily digest

        
    }
}

public class WeeklyDigest : ITask
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        //Weekly Digest
    }
}
```

**Get this library from github**
https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler

OR

using Nuget **Install-Package FluentScheduler**

Answer (score 0):

Not built into Azure SQL - but there are 3rd party services that allow scheduling (Aditi and Cotega are mentioned here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b2ae724f-4509-4c0f-aef4-58ce8be60f1a/is-there-an-equivalent-job-regular-sql-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted)

If you have Worker Roles (or other VMs running in Azure) available - you can roll your own schedule process.  This, obviously, involves paying for that compute time.

If this is an option (i.e. you are paying for spinning up a VM) - you also have the option of running your own instance of SQL Server on your own VM and using "standard" SQL Server (with a standard Agent, etc.) - rather than hosting your DBs in Azure SQL.  This would be a very expensive alternative...

Personally, I would look at using a Mobile Service to call the SP and then devise a way to schedule a call to the service.  Not robust - but quick and dirty and cheep...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have just announced Windows Azure Scheduler, which includes a free tier.  See the [pricing page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/scheduler/)